# `dig -4` returns IPv6 address

Tags: ipv6, ipv4, dig

Why would `dig -4` return an IPv6 address?

```
% dig -v
DiG 9.16.5
%
% dig -4 @8.8.8.8 TXT o-o.myaddr.l.google.com | grep TXT
; <<>> DiG 9.16.5 <<>> -4 @8.8.8.8 TXT o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
;o-o.myaddr.l.google.com.       IN      TXT
o-o.myaddr.l.google.com. 54     IN      TXT     "2a0a:b640:1:5a::a07d"
```

Fear not, I'm using a VPN.

Is this a bug with the Google nameserver?  (If so, how would I report it?)

Interestingly, the output is different if adding `-c IN`:

```
% diff <(dig -4 -c IN @8.8.8.8 TXT o-o.myaddr.l.google.com) <(dig -4 @8.8.8.8 TXT o-o.myaddr.l.google.com)
2c2
< ; <<>> DiG 9.16.5 <<>> -4 -c IN @8.8.8.8 TXT o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
---
> ; <<>> DiG 9.16.5 <<>> -4 @8.8.8.8 TXT o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
6,7c6,7
< ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 35377
< ;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
---
> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27019
> ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 3
11c11
< ; COOKIE: ffdced2ffd1d8fb9ca1b1c3c5f53070accd8e6ece4fb266f (good)
---
> ; COOKIE: 8042de852de231e1242187435f53070bdddc4b80f19c7711 (good)
13c13
< ;TXT.             IN  A
---
> ;o-o.myaddr.l.google.com. IN  TXT
15,25c15,16
< ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
< .         7956    IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2020090401 1800 900 604800 86400
< 
< ;; Query time: 66 msec
< ;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
< ;; WHEN: Sat Sep 05 10:33:31 +07 2020
< ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 135
< 
< ;; Got answer:
< ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16524
< ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
---
> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
> o-o.myaddr.l.google.com. 28   IN  TXT "2a0a:b640:1:5a::a07d"
27,31c18,26
< ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
< ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
< ; COOKIE: ffdced2ffd1d8fb9e51dd6995f53070b3d32c82e71242836 (good)
< ;; QUESTION SECTION:
< ;o-o.myaddr.l.google.com. IN  A
---
> ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
> google.com.       121655  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
> google.com.       121655  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
> google.com.       121655  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
> google.com.       121655  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
> 
> ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
> ns1.google.com.       340694  IN  A   216.239.32.10
> ns1.google.com.       340694  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:32::a
33c28
< ;; Query time: 76 msec
---
> ;; Query time: 73 msec
36c31
< ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 80
---
> ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 229
```

Answer (score 5):

This is you not doing things properly.  ☺

The reported `-c IN` effect is because you didn't do that right.
Both queries were clearly `IN`, as that is the default class anyway.
But notice that the one that failed was looking up the domain name `TXT.`, not the domain name `o-o.myaddr.l.google.com.`.
You confused `dig` and made it think that the resource record type argument was the domain name.

Notice that handling `type domain-name` as arguments is a crutch for people who do not read the `dig` manual, where it clearly states that the order is `domain-name type class`.  ☺  (Knot DNS's `kdig` has the subtly different order `domain-name class type` in its manual, but also tries to cope with people who give the arguments the wrong way around.)

Notice also that the manual recommends explicitly using `-t` and `-q` to avoid all ambiguity with (top-level) domain names.

The `-4` isn't really anything to do with it.
That just makes it speak IPv4 to the DNS server.
But you got the DNS server wrong.

It's the `@8.8.8.8` that is the important factor.

This query is supposed to be performed directly against Google's *content* DNS servers.
They are (at the time of writing) these in the IPv4 world:

```
% dnsqr ns l.google.com. | awk '/answer:/ {print $5}' | xargs dnsip
216.239.34.10
216.239.32.10
216.239.36.10
216.239.38.10
%
```

These content DNS servers return the originating IP address and any EDNS0 information as a `TXT` resource record set when queried for that domain name.

You are performing it against Google's *public resolving proxy* DNS servers instead.
You are getting the EDNS0 information and originating IP address *of the back end of the particular proxy server employed* (8.8.8.8 being anycast) rather than your machine's own IP address.
Google's public proxy DNS server is what contacts Google's content DNS server, and so it is the IP address and EDNS0 information of *that* transaction that is returned by the content DNS server in the resource record set, back to the Google proxy and thence from the proxy to you.

The fact that the TTL is 54 seconds, instead of the 60 seconds that Google's *content* DNS server employs, is a big clue here, as is the fact that it is not *your* IPv6 address.

The reason that the abbreviated forms of using `dig` and `host` given in most doco, without explicitly directing the transaction to Google's content DNS servers, usually happens to work is that it goes through a *local* resolving proxy DNS server *on your own machine*, whose back-end queries of course originate with *your machine's* IP address.
Having a local resolving proxy DNS server was and is the norm in the Unix and Linux world.
This isn't (non-Server) Microsoft Windows.

However: Use *someone else's* resolving proxy DNS server, by forwarding from your own proxy DNS server, configuring someone else's server in `/etc/resolv.conf`, or (as here) by explicitly directing the query to somewhere like 8.8.8.8/1.1.1.1/9.9.9.9, and you'll get information about the back-end of that someone else's proxy DNS server.

```
% DNSCACHEIP=1.1.1.1 dnsqr txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com:
105 bytes, 1+1+0+0 records, response, noerror
query: 16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
answer: o-o.myaddr.l.google.com 36 TXT \0342400:cb00:63:1024::a29e:2192
%
% DNSCACHEIP=1.0.0.1 dnsqr txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com:
105 bytes, 1+1+0+0 records, response, noerror
query: 16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
answer: o-o.myaddr.l.google.com 12 TXT \0342400:cb00:63:1024::a29e:2192
%
% DNSCACHEIP=9.9.9.9 dnsqr txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com:
71 bytes, 1+1+0+0 records, response, noerror
query: 16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
answer: o-o.myaddr.l.google.com 60 TXT \0212620:171:fa:f0::7
%
```

It shouldn't be shocking that the back-end of a resolving proxy DNS server run by CloudFlare has a CloudFlare-assigned IPv6 address.  ☺

Some of them even have multiple back-end IP addresses, either because they truly have that or (more likely) as the anycasting moves around.
(I paused a little between some of these.)

```
% DNSCACHEIP=8.8.8.8 dnsqr txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com:
114 bytes, 1+2+0+0 records, response, noerror
query: 16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
answer: o-o.myaddr.l.google.com 59 TXT \01574.125.181.14
answer: o-o.myaddr.l.google.com 59 TXT "edns0-client-subnet\040Ahem!
% DNSCACHEIP=8.8.8.8 dnsqr txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com:
124 bytes, 1+2+0+0 records, response, noerror
query: 16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
answer: o-o.myaddr.l.google.com 59 TXT \0272a00:1450:400c:c01::106
answer: o-o.myaddr.l.google.com 59 TXT "edns0-client-subnet\040Ahem!
% DNSCACHEIP=8.8.8.8 dnsqr txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com:
124 bytes, 1+2+0+0 records, response, noerror
query: 16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
answer: o-o.myaddr.l.google.com 59 TXT \0272a00:1450:400c:c01::107
answer: o-o.myaddr.l.google.com 59 TXT "edns0-client-subnet\040Ahem!
%
% DNSCACHEIP=9.9.9.10 dnsqr txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com:
71 bytes, 1+1+0+0 records, response, noerror
query: 16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
answer: o-o.myaddr.l.google.com 60 TXT \0212620:171:fa:f0::3
% DNSCACHEIP=9.9.9.10 dnsqr txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com:
66 bytes, 1+1+0+0 records, response, noerror
query: 16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
answer: o-o.myaddr.l.google.com 31 TXT \01474.63.26.248
% DNSCACHEIP=9.9.9.10 dnsqr txt o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com:
66 bytes, 1+1+0+0 records, response, noerror
query: 16 o-o.myaddr.l.google.com
answer: o-o.myaddr.l.google.com 60 TXT \01474.63.26.250
%
```

`dnsqr` is dumping `TXT` resource records in a slightly naïve way here.
Those octal escapes are just the length byte.
I should probably fix that.  ☺

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2000). *["content" and "proxy" DNS servers.](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/dns-server-roles.html)*  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2003). *[Whence one obtains proxy DNS service](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/dns-obtaining-proxy-service.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2004). *[What DNS query resolution is](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/dns-query-resolution.html)*
  .  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[Daniel J. Bernstein's softwares all in one](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/djbwares/)*.  Softwares.